# Hi there, it seems an error when click on customer id

Tags: customer-account

```
Fatal error:Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion' not found in /home2/sjaved/public_html/dev/umu/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491
```

How to fix it..??

Comment: Have you validated that the class exists? `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Accordion.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Accordion.php` exists.
If it doesn't get it [from here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Accordion.php). Change the branch to fit your magento version.

Comment: Accordion.php is already  saved in this folder...